# Angular home page is not showing

Tags: angular

I am facing issue with angular 4 ,the issue I just start the angular application by using the following command i.e ng serve .
Then I went to the browser and typed the following Url localhost:4200 but web page is showing connection has terminated or failed. Could you please help on this. 
I'm facing this issue in windows10.

Comment: Do you get any message in your terminal after typing `ng serve` ?

Comment: There is not remotely enough here to go on

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
ng serve --o
```

### OR

```
ng serve --open
```